# Powershell get-childitem needs a lot of memory

Tags: powershell, directory

My question is pretty much the same as the one posted on metafilter.

I need to use a PowerShell script to scan through a large amount of files. The issue is that it seems that the "Get-ChildItem" function insists on shoving the whole folder and file structure in memory. Since the drive has over a million files in over 30,000 folders, the script needs a lot of memory.

http://ask.metafilter.com/134940/PowerShell-recursive-processing-of-all-files-and-folders-without-OutOfMemory-exception

All what I need is the name, size and location of the files.

What I do since now is:

```
$filesToIndex = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }
```

It works but I don't want to punish my memory :-)

Best regards,
greenhoorn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to optimize the script to use less memory, you need to properly utilize the pipeline. What you are doing is saving the result of Get-ChildItem -recurse into memory, all of it! What you could do is something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
    if (-not($_.PSIsContainer)) {
        # do stuff / get info you need here
    }
}
```

This way you are always streaming the data through the pipeline and you will see that PowerShell will consume less memory (if done correctly).

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer. I'm new to Powershell and don't really know how to use the pipelines. But it seems to be a very nice thing :-)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to help is to reduce the size of the objects your saving by paring them down to just the properties you're interested in.

```
$filesToIndex = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |
 Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
 Select Name,Fullname,Length
```

Comment: This will still throw all the file objects into memory...  see @ojk's answer.